# Is there a way to redo modal arguments?

Tags: python

Hey is it possible to change redo_last options during modal?
This script adds a plane in edit mode and then obviously adds 
a new plane every time it loops, is there a way to make the plane and then toggle through the rotation without repeating the add plane operator?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "test_modal",
    "author": "test",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "description": "test",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
import blf
import bgl


def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    screen_x = bpy.context.region.width / 2
    font_id = 0
    blf.size(font_id, 32, 72)

    # X
    if self.axis == 'X':
        bgl.glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1)
        blf.position(font_id, screen_x, 7, 0)
        blf.draw(font_id, "Axis: X")
    # Y
    if self.axis == 'Y':
        bgl.glColor4f(0, 1, 0, 1)
        blf.position(font_id, screen_x, 7, 0)
        blf.draw(font_id, "Axis: Y")
    # Z
    if self.axis == 'Z':
        bgl.glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 1)
        blf.position(font_id, screen_x, 7, 0)
        blf.draw(font_id, "Axis: Z")


class TestModal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.test_modal"
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'GRAB_CURSOR', 'BLOCKING'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if self.axis == 'X':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius = 10, rotation = (1.5708, 0, 0))
        elif self.axis == 'Y':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius = 10, rotation = (0, 1.5708, 0))
        elif self.axis == 'Z':
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius = 10, rotation = (0, 0, 1.5708))
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'Z' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            self.axis = "Z"
            self.execute(context)
        if event.type == 'X' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            self.axis = "X"
            self.execute(context)
        if event.type == 'Y' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            self.axis = "Y"
            self.execute(context)

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            self.report({'INFO'}, 'Completed')
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in ('RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'):
            bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type = 'VERT')
            self.report({'INFO'}, 'Cancelled')
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        args = (self, context)
        self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        # store vars
        self.axis = "X"
        # deselect all
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
        self.execute(context)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestModal)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestModal)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Wrong use of a modal operator, create an object with one operator and then move it with a different modal operator. For example when you extrude, one operator creates the extra mesh and then starts the modal translate operator. Another approach would be to only create when invoked or record that you have created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[BMesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#module-bmesh) Approach**

I've rejigged your script to use an edit mode [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#module-bmesh).  Adds a plane on press of "axis key"  X, Y or Z at the cursor location. Rotates the mesh locally about given axis.

It will keep rotating mesh 90 degrees on given axis. (4 times will return to starting point.  Test event type vs previously set axis to remove this behaviour.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "test_modal",
    "author": "test",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "description": "test",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
import blf
import bgl
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians
axes = "XYZ"
def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    screen_x = context.region.width / 2
    font_id = 0
    blf.size(font_id, 32, 72)
    col = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    if self.axis in axes:
        col[axes.index(self.axis)] = 1
        bgl.glColor4f(*col)
        blf.position(font_id, screen_x, 7, 0)
        blf.draw(font_id, "Axis: %s" % self.axis)        


class TestModal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.test_modal"
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'GRAB_CURSOR', 'BLOCKING'}
    bm = None
    verts = None
    mwi = None    
    def execute(self, context):
        loc = self.mwi * context.scene.cursor_location
        if self.verts is None:
            self.bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(context.object.data)
            ret = bmesh.ops.create_grid(self.bm, size=10)
            self.verts = ret["verts"]

            bmesh.ops.translate(
                    self.bm,
                    verts=self.verts,
                    vec=loc)

        bmesh.ops.rotate(
                self.bm,
                verts=self.verts,
                cent=loc,
                matrix=Matrix.Rotation(radians(90.0), 
                        3, self.axis))
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(context.object.data)

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in axes and event.value == 'PRESS':
            self.axis = event.type
            self.execute(context)

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            self.report({'INFO'}, 'Completed')
            context.area.tag_redraw()
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in ('RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'):
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            context.area.tag_redraw()
            if self.bm:
                for v in self.verts:
                    self.bm.verts.remove(v)
                # bmesh.ops.delete(self.bm, geom=self.verts) # ??
                bmesh.update_edit_mesh(context.object.data)    
            self.report({'INFO'}, 'Cancelled')

            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        args = (self, context)
        self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        # store vars
        self.axis = "V"
        self.mwi = context.object.matrix_world.inverted()
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestModal)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestModal)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you , I have learned a lot from this. So is it impossible to do it the way I was trying? Because redoing would open up so many options.

Comment: Not sure, I generally steer clear of the undo / redo stack. (can go horribly wrong in my experience lol)  A big issue as I see it, is running the operators you want to redo / undo in a modal operator.  Perhaps the info in comment link in other q is helpful?